# Adonis.js in production : ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/public/assets/.vite/manifest.json'

Tags: javascript, nginx, adonis.js

I ask my first question on stack because I despair :(
Sorry if my english isn't good !

I develop a simple Quiz app with adonisjs to learn the framework and application deployment.

My problem is during the deployment. In developpement, I had no problem. Everthing works wtih "pnpm run dev" !

Now, I already clone the project on my vps with git in /var/www/myproject, run the 'pnpm run build' and configure the nginx "correctly".

I run the command 'node bin/server.js' (I created a service to run the command when the VPS starts.)

The nginx configuration :

```
server {
    #root /var/www/projectName;

    server_name mydomain.fr;

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3333;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/qfelbinger.fr/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/qfelbinger.fr/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

And now when I go to my domain with my browser, I have a problem with Vite I think (I have no experience with this tools):

The error message :

`ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/public/assets/.vite/manifest.json'`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFHwm.png)

So, I go in the folder and I SEE the file with same right of all file in le project.

My vite configuration :

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import adonisjs from '@adonisjs/vite/client';
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        adonisjs({
            entrypoints: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            reload: ['resources/views/**/*.edge'],
        }),
    ],
});
```

I use Edge template for the frontend.

If anyone have an idea, I'm here :) And I can give any information if you need it !

I try to install all project again with no changes.
I execute "pnpm i" to install dev dependency but I know it's usless, so, nothing change...
And I don't see anything on Vite documentation since few days...

Comment: Did you run `pnpm run build`?

Comment: Yes and in the build folder I run the command `node bin/server.js` and just after this on my site I have the error :/